# Problemas con OneToMany JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo las siguiente tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer un OneToMany de ta_pedidos(One) con ta_subpedidos(Many), ta_subpedidos tiene una FK del id de pedidos, pero al hacer el Insert, el FK de ta_subpedidos, no se le está seteando el id de pedido dinámicamente, ya intenté de muchas maneras, pero no logro hacer que haga el insert de los subpedidos.

También intenté hacerlo unidireccional que así es como quisiera hacerlo pero aún así no logré nada :/

Java:

PedidoEntity.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "FI_ID_PEDIDO")
private int idPedido;
@Column(name = "FC_CODIGO_PEDIDO")
private String codigoPedido;
@Column(name = "FK_FI_FORMA_PAGO")
private int formaPago;
@Column(name = "FK_FI_TIPO_ENVIO")
private int tipoEnvio;
@Column(name = "FC_NOMBRE")
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "FC_APELLIDOS")
private String apellidos;
@Column(name = "FC_NUMERO")
private String numero;
@Column(name = "FC_CORREO")
private String correo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idPedido", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SubpedidosEntity> subPedidos;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_FI_ID_DIRECCION")
private DireccionEnvioEntity direccion;
```

SubpedidoEntity.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "FI_ID_SUBPEDIDO")
private int idSubpedido;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_FI_ID_PEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "FI_ID_PEDIDO")
private PedidosEntity idPedido;

@Column(name = "FC_ID_PRODUCTO")
private String idProducto;

@Column(name = "FI_CANTIDAD")
private int cantidad;
```

Y estoy mandando la siguiente petición:

```
{
"codigoPedido": "PRUEBA",
"formaPago": 1,
"tipoEnvio": 2,
"nombre": "NombrePrueba",
"apellidos": "ApellidoPrueba",
"numero": "1234567890",
"correo": "correo@hotmail.com",
"subPedidos": [
   {
       "idProducto": "pruebaId",
       "cantidad": 5
    },
    {
       "idProducto": "pruebaId2",
       "cantidad": 2
    }
],
"direccion": {
    "calle": "CallePrueba",
    "numExterior": "500",
    "numInterior": "0",
    "colonia": "ColoniaPrueba",
    "referencias": "Referencia Prueba"
}
```

}

Y para insertar hago un save para PedidoEntity

```
public PedidosEntity guardaPedido(PedidoEntity request) {
    PedidosEntity response = null;
    try {
        response = pedidoRepo.save(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage() + "\n" +  e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Al momento de hacer el Insert, me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    ta_direcion_envio
    (fc_calle, fc_colonia, fc_num_exterior, fc_num_interior, fc_referencias) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ta_pedidos
        (fc_apellidos, fc_codigo_pedido, fc_correo, fk_fi_id_direccion, fk_fi_forma_pago, fc_nombre, fc_numero, fk_fi_tipo_envio) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ta_subpedido
        (fi_cantidad, fk_fi_id_pedido, fc_id_producto) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2021-02-06 00:45:27.468  WARN 3136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2021-02-06 00:45:27.468 ERROR 3136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'fk_fi_id_pedido' cannot be null
Error could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Al insertar en la tabla de ta_subpedidos, no lo hace porque el el valor para la columna FK_FI_ID_PEDIDO, no se le está setenando dinámicamente, ya intenté con muchos ejemplos y de diferentes maneras, pero no logro hacer que inserte ese OneToMany, alguien tiene una idea de cómo solucionarlo?